# How can I replicate plot.lda() with of R `tidymodels`

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidymodels

I would like to replicate the plot.lda print method using `ggplot2` and `tidymodels`.  Is there an elegant way to get the plot?

I think I can fake the `augment()` function, which does not have a lda method, by using `predict()` and bind it onto the original data.

Here is an example with the base R and `tidymodels` code:

```
library(ISLR2)
library(MASS)

# First base R
train <- Smarket$Year < 2005

lda.fit <-
  lda(
    Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2,
    data = Smarket,
    subset = train
  )

plot(lda.fit)


# Next tidymodels

library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(discrim)

lda_spec <- discrim_linear() %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("MASS")

the_rec <- recipe(
  Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2, 
  data = Smarket
)

the_workflow<- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(the_rec) %>% 
  add_model(lda_spec)

Smarket_train <- Smarket %>%
  filter(Year != 2005)

the_workflow_fit_lda_fit <- 
  fit(the_workflow, data = Smarket_train) %>% 
  extract_fit_parsnip()

# now my attempt to do the plot

predictions <- predict(the_workflow_fit_lda_fit, 
                 new_data = Smarket_train, 
                 type = "raw"
         )[[3]] %>% 
  as.vector()

bind_cols(Smarket_train, .fitted = predictions) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=.fitted)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(density)),binwidth = .5) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-4, 4, by = 2))+
  facet_grid(vars(Direction)) +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("Density")
```

There must be a better way to do this.... thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a combination of `extract_fit_*()` and `parsnip:::repair_call()`. The `plot.lda()` method uses the `$call` object in the LDA fit, which we need to adjust since the call object from using tidymodels will be different than using `lda()` directly.

```r
library(ISLR2)
library(MASS)

# First base R
train <- Smarket$Year < 2005

lda.fit <-
  lda(
    Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2,
    data = Smarket,
    subset = train
  )

# Next tidymodels

library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(discrim)

lda_spec <- discrim_linear() %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("MASS")

the_rec <- recipe(
  Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2, 
  data = Smarket
)

the_workflow <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(the_rec) %>% 
  add_model(lda_spec)

Smarket_train <- Smarket %>%
  filter(Year != 2005)

the_workflow_fit_lda_fit <- 
  fit(the_workflow, data = Smarket_train)
```

After fitting both models, we can inspect the `$call` objects and we see that they are different.

```r
lda.fit$call
#> lda(formula = Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2, data = Smarket, subset = train)

extract_fit_engine(the_workflow_fit_lda_fit)$call
#> lda(formula = ..y ~ ., data = data)
```

The `parsnip::repair_call()` function will replace `data` with the data we pass in. Additionally, we will rename the response of the data to `..y` to match the call.

```r
the_workflow_fit_lda_fit %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>%
  parsnip::repair_call(rename(Smarket_train, ..y = Direction)) %>%
  extract_fit_engine() %>%
  plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. You just increased my tidyverse IQ by several points. Do you know what you read to learn how to attack this question?  I had never seen `repair_call()` or `extract_fit_engine()`. I would love a gentle introduction.

Comment: There is a brief introduction here https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/07/tidymodels-july-2021/#object-extraction